# How to format User().DisplayName to display the same as People field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint form, customized in Power Apps, where I need to hide a group of fields if the current user = user identified in people field.

Basically I have a requestor field (people field) at the top of my form.  I don't want whoever is identified there to be able to see several approval fields I have in the form.  I created a label and set it to the people field's datacardvalue: Datacardvalue2.Selected.Displayname.

And I set another label to User().Displayname as a test.  The Datacardvalue2 label displays last name, first name, and my department/company.  But User().Displayname is formatted with first name, last name.

So is there a way I can format either so that they match?  Or is there a better way I can hide those fields if the user selected in Datacardvalue2 = the current user?  I would leverage the 'Created By' field, but the Requestor won't always be the same user who submits the form.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of display name, use email property to match. 2 users in the company may have same display name sometimes. If email format in people column is not same as User().Email then you can get email from office 365 users connector instead of User().Email. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Chris, did you try below solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi Ganesh.  Yes it worked exactly as I needed it to.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the Email property instead of display name for comparing users.

Two users in the company may have same display names sometimes.

So, try setting `Visible` property of controls to something like this:

```
!(User().Email = Datacardvalue2.Selected.Email)
```

It will hide the controls if currently logged in user email matches with the email of person selected in data card.

---

If `User().Email` does not have same format like person email from data card, you can add Office 365 Users data source in your app and then use:

```
!(Office365Users.MyProfileV2().Mail = Datacardvalue2.Selected.Email)
```

**Note**: You can set one variable in `App.OnStart` to store the user profile instead of every time calling Office365Users API call. Like:

```
Set(gvUserObj, Office365Users.MyProfileV2())
```

Then use conditions like for below for multiple controls:

```
!(gvUserObj.Mail = Datacardvalue2.Selected.Email)
```